# Mockito ArgumentCaptor doesn't capture argurment in catch block

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I wrote this service

```
public class FirstService {

    private final SecondService secondService;

    public FirstService(SecondService secondService) {
        this.secondService = secondService;
    }

    public void hz() throws Exception {
        try {
            methodThrowsException();
        } catch (Exception e){
            secondService.handleErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private void methodThrowsException() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("message");
    }
}
```

And this service:

```
public class SecondService {
    public void handleErrorMessage(String message) {}
}
```

I need to verify that `handleErrorMessage` was called. I wrote a test:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

public class FirstServiceTest {
    private FirstService firstService;
    private SecondService secondService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        secondService = mock(SecondService.class);
        firstService = new FirstService(secondService);
    }

    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void hz() throws Exception {
        firstService.hz();
        ArgumentCaptor<String> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        verify(secondService).handleErrorMessage(argumentCaptor.capture());
        String value = argumentCaptor.getValue();

        assertEquals("message", value);
    }
}
```

Test pass. But if I change `assertEquals("message666", value);` it still pass. If I don't throw an exception in catch block - ArgumentCaptor captures argument, but when I throw an exception it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Your test is annotated:
`@Test(expected = Exception.class)`

This means that the test will pass if an `Exception` (or any subclass of) makes it up to the top level. This happens on the first line of your test:

```
    firstService.hz();
```

This is why it passes. Unfortunately, that exception means that the rest of your test is never run, since that exception propagates up and out of your test method.

A bit ugly, but this snippet does what you want:

```
    @Test
    public void hz() throws Exception {

        try {
            firstService.hz();

            // If we get here, then we didn't throw an exception - fail
            Assert.fail();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Exception was expected - disregard and continue
            // no-op
        }
        ArgumentCaptor<String> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        verify(secondService).handleErrorMessage(argumentCaptor.capture());
        String value = argumentCaptor.getValue();

        assertEquals("message", value);
    }
```

The above runs your method, and catches the exception (and fails if you didn't get the expected exception). Then, it proceeds, and runs the rest of your test.

JUnit 5 provides a slightly cleaner way, but you'd have to migrate:

```
    @Test
    public void hz() throws Exception {

        Assertions.assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> firstService.hz());

        ArgumentCaptor<String> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        verify(secondService).handleErrorMessage(argumentCaptor.capture());
        String value = argumentCaptor.getValue();

        assertEquals("asdf", value);
    }
```

Comment: I catch the exception in a try-catch block and rethrow it after calling `handleErrorMessage` method.

Comment: Yep - your rethrow makes it all the way to the top level, and out through firstService.hz().

Try removing the `(expected=)` and you'll see it in the test output.

(I copied and ran your code :) )

Comment: Hi PavelPetrashov, the point is firstService.hz(). No matter what you do in this method, at final you're throwing an exception. In the test class when you invoke firstService.hz(); it's going to raise the exception, so no code below is going to be executed. As Thalex said your test is passing because it's expecting an Exception by @Test(expected = Exception.class)